# How to rename a label while maintaining its nodes' relationships, and merge it into another label?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I made a mistake on my server where my nodes were saving as `:Studio` instead of `:GameStudio` like I wanted them to.

Now my database has both `:Studio` and `:GameStudio` nodes, however I'd really like to rename all of the `:Studio` nodes.

Is there a query I can write that will rename the `:Studio` (while maintaining their relationships) and merge them into `:GameStudio`? `:Studio` and `:GameStudio` have the same properties and unique by `id`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very easy. Here's the query to do this:

```
MATCH (s:Studio)
SET s:GameStudio
REMOVE s:Studio
```

Also, you may not know this, but nodes can have multiple labels, which is very useful if certain labels are more specific versions of other labels, or if the same nodes need to be shared between different domains using different labels.

It may be helpful to keep the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) on hand, especially if you're new to Neo4j and Cypher.